# Did McClelland ever mentioned about two aditional needs in motivation?

Tags: motivation

I've been getting classes on psychology of the motivation and my intructor mentioned about McClelland's theory of needs.

Although the [wiki entry on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_theory) is somewhat clear about it. It doesn't mention about the necessity of determination neither the necessity of competence.

In my class my intructor attributed this to McClelland to which *him* defined those as:

Necessity of determination:

Tendency of to feel protagonist of your his or her own destiny.

Necessity of competence:

Tendency of a person to measure one's own performance with that of others.

I'm not sure where did my professor got those or if McClelland ever mentioned those in his theory.

Perhaps someone with experience in this field can offer some guidance on what's difference between them and how does exactly apply to a person's motivation?. Does it exist a hierarchy here as with Maslow's?.